# What is the --jar-file and --class-name options in Sqoop merge command

Tags: merge, sqoop, cloudera-cdh

I tried to run these following sqoop merge command in cloudera quickstart VM:

```
sqoop merge --merge-key department_id \
  --new-data /user/cloudera/sqoop_merge/departments_delta \
  --onto /user/cloudera/sqoop_merge/departments \
  --target-dir /user/cloudera/sqoop_merge/departments_stage \
  --class-name departments \
  --jar-file
```

I am getting the following error:

> Missing argument for option: jar-file

In sqoop documentation I found this.

> --jar-file  Specify the name of the jar to load the record class from.

I am getting error for the

> --class-name
>   command also.

what are these two commands and what are the expected arguments that are to be passed to these commands?

Answer (score 3):

When you initially imported data to hdfs using `sqoop`, `sqoop` must have created java files for each imported table (usually in same dir from where you ran `sqoop import` command for `departments` table or if `--outdir` used than classes should be in that location). you need to package those classes in jar file and use that in `merge`:

so if you package `department.java` class in `mydataTypes.jar` file than `sqoop merge`command should be:

```
sqoop merge --merge-key department_id \
  --new-data /user/cloudera/sqoop_merge/departments_delta \
  --onto /user/cloudera/sqoop_merge/departments \
  --target-dir /user/cloudera/sqoop_merge/departments_stage \
  --class-name departments \
  --jar-file /path/to/mydataTypes.jar
```

[sqoop_guide](https://sqoop.apache.org/docs/1.4.6/SqoopUserGuide.html#_syntax_8)

> To parse the dataset and extract the key column, the auto-generated
>   class from a previous import must be used. You should specify the
>   class name and jar file with `--class-name` and `--jar-file`. If this
>   is not available you can recreate the class using the `codegen` tool.

Comment: how do you find or create the `.jar` files though?

Comment: go to dir in which java files are and execute this command: `jar cf <jar-file-name> <input-file(s)>` - [Examples](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/build.html)

Comment: How do you find the dir in which the java files are?

Comment: already answered - "(usually in same dir from where you ran sqoop import command for departments table or if --outdir used than classes should be in that location)."

Comment: Yes, but how can I find the actual path from the command-line interface?

Comment: Also, which `.jar` file do I use? The one for the new-data or the old-data?